# By changing the value from int to float the total value gets changed Can anyone explain why? plz

Tags: c++, c, algorithm

I have tried several to identify why, but I could not do so, so if anyone get identified please let me know..

```
#include <stdio.h>
    
int main()
{
    int i,n=1;
    float div=0,sum=0,j=1;
    for(i=1;i<=7;i++)
    {
        j=1;
       for(n=1;n<=i;n++)
       {
           j=j*n;
       }
    div=i/j+div;
    
    }
    printf(" %f",div);

    return 0;
}
```

actually it is a program to display "  Write a
program to add first seven terms of the following series using For-Loop :

```
(1/1!)+(2/2!)+(3/3!)+…………  "
```

By running the above program we get result as 2.72 which is correct one. but if we run code below

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i,n=1,j=1;
    float div=0,sum=0;
    for(i=1;i<=7;i++)
    {
        j=1;
       for(n=1;n<=i;n++)
       {
           j=j*n;
       }
    div=i/j+div;
    
    }
    printf(" %f",div);

    return 0;
}
```

but what actually done is changing `j=1` from int to float and vice versa. but the result is varying..

Comment: `i/j` if both of those are of `int` type then the result is an `int` with the decimal part truncated away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It makes a difference here:

```
div=i/j+div;
```

When the `/` operator is evaluated in the second piece of code, both operands have type `int` so integer division is performed which truncates any fractional part.  When `j` is declared as type `double`, floating point division is performed and no truncation occurs.

Comment: very thank you for your answer, it really helped me a lot..!

Comment: @DharnieshPR Glad I could help.  Feel free to [accept this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if you found it useful.

Answer (score 0):

you cant divide by integer and expect a float answer, you can cast j to float as follows:

```
div = i / (float)j + div;
```

which will give you the answer you want

Comment: very thank you for your answer, it really helped me a lot..!,

 But one thing if we declare (float) near a int value does it become a float value?and similarly if we declare a (char) near a int value does it display ASCII value

Comment: @DharnieshPR yep! [read more](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/typecasting/)